# Logarithm of Gaussian converting from zero

Tags: erlang, gaussian, elixir, logarithm

I have a vector V of 256 position. For each position in the vector I want to calculate the density from a Gaussian distribution:

```
V[0] -> p(V[0])
V[1] -> p(V[1])
...
V[255] -> p(V[255])
```

After that I want to multiply all the probabilities together:

```
p(V[0]) * p(V[1]) * ... * p(V[255])
```

The problem with this method in my implementation is that each probability is high (around ~400), so I cannot multiply everything together.

A workaround for that would be taking the log of each Gaussian and then adding all together:

```
V[0] -> log(p(V[0]))
V[1] -> log(p(V[1]))
...
V[255] -> log(p(V[255]))

log(p(V[0])) + log(p(V[1])) + ... + log(p(V[255]))
```

But when I try to do that I get an error when the Gaussian results in zero.

Having this in mind, is there any workaround the `log(0)` problem? Would be an accurate representation replace `log(0)`for `0`?

#### EDIT:

So, for the record, If I try the normal method (multiplying), the error that I get is this one:

```
iex(6)> Naive.CLI.main(["~/data/usps.csv", "~/indices/17.csv"])
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
             :erlang.*(417.62100246853674, 6.504406716503509e307)
```

From what I understand the numbers are too high for the multiplication take effect.

Here is what I did (and I think should be the right idea):

```
def gaussian(vector, mean, variance) do
  vector
  |> Enum.zip(mean)
  |> Enum.zip(variance)
  |> Enum.map(fn {{e, m}, v} -> {e, m, v} end)
  |> Enum.map(fn {e, m, v} -> calculate(e, m, v) end)
  |> Enum.map(fn e ->
    if e == 0.0 do
      0.0
    else
      :math.log10(e)
    end
  end)
end

defp calculate(elem, mean, variance) do
  (1/:math.sqrt(2*:math.pi*variance)) *
  :math.exp(-0.5*(((elem - mean)*(elem - mean)) / variance))
end
```

Basically if the Gaussian results in zero, I return zero as well.

Comment: _"The problem with this method in my implementation is that each probability is high (around ~400), so I cannot multiply everything together."_ Why not?

Comment: the error that I get from that is this onde: ** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression :erlang.*(417.62100246853674, 6.504406716503509e307), mind you that I am working with elixir

Comment: Maybe tag your answer with elixir and erlang?

Comment: oh, my bad, I thought this would be an error in any language.

Comment: @lhahn , sorry, but I do not understand you problem. If in your calculating at the transition to logarithm  to get log(0), then the initial product will be equal to 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Naive Bayes \*high\* probabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417706/naive-bayes-high-probabilities)

Comment: I wanted to make the problem more clear, should I delete the other?

Comment: First, probability cannot exceed `1`, by definition of probability. So if your probability is not normalized already, you can just scale it and nothing changes.

Comment: Shouldn't the probability be between 0 and 1? Also, I don't know if you noticed but the second number has a very high exponent: 6.504406716503509e307 (see the `e307` at the end). Finally, `log(0)` is not defined, why are you reaching log(0)?

Comment: As Atomic_alarm noted, if you get log(0), then the original product is 0, so you could catch the resulting error and return 0 for the whole computation. However, it'd help to get the whole assignment to give you a really helpful advice.

Comment: The "probabilities are high" because the integral of a Gaussian curve must be 1. Since the variance is really small (e-8), the results from the Gaussian are high.

Comment: @lhahn Erlang and Elixir use bignum arithmetic with integers. If you're able to write your code such that it only uses integers throughout, it will be able to handle arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: @orlp Think how large a number 400 ^ 256  is.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci 1340780792994259709957402499820584612747936582059239337772356144372176403007354697680187429816690342769003185818648605085375388281194656994643364900608409600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...